# FirebaseRemoteConfig Error "No value of type 'String' exists for parameter key"

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

I am using Firebase Core and some other Features, but not Remote Config. Multiple times a second the following Output is on Logcat.

Where can I disable the Remote Config functionality or even set those non-existing values?

Dependencies:

```
// Project
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.2.0'

classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.26.1'

// Module
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:preference-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.3'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.11.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.5.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.2.4'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.jsibbold:zoomage:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'

implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.9'
```

```
W/FirebaseRemoteConfig: No value of type 'String' exists for parameter key 'sessions_max_length_minutes'.
W/FirebaseRemoteConfig: No value of type 'String' exists for parameter key 'sessions_max_length_minutes'.
W/FirebaseRemoteConfig: No value of type 'String' exists for parameter key 'sessions_feature_enabled'.
W/FirebaseRemoteConfig: No value of type 'String' exists for parameter key 'sessions_max_length_minutes'.
W/FirebaseRemoteConfig: No value of type 'String' exists for parameter key 'fpr_vc_trace_sampling_rate'.
W/FirebaseRemoteConfig: No value of type 'String' exists for parameter key 'sessions_feature_enabled'.
W/FirebaseRemoteConfig: No value of type 'String' exists for parameter key 'fpr_vc_trace_sampling_rate'.
```

*It is not causing any problems I think, just annoying that it spams the Console.*

Comment: If you have feedback about Firebase SDKs, contact Firebase support.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/

Comment: @DougStevenson I am not having feedback, I am just wondering where this output comes from.

Comment: I've created an [issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/1786) on GitHub!

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Firebase answer to my bug report:

*It seems that you're getting some warning about Remote Config. We managed to reproduce on our end, and our engineers have confirmed that this is working as intended. This happens because the Performance Monitoring SDK was added on your app. This is because Performance Monitoring uses Firebase Remote Config internally. However, our engineers have confirmed that they will try to reduce these warnings in the future. For now, you can ignore these as it's only a warning, and should not affect the app's performance.*

Comment: In the meantime, if you don't want to see them while you are debugging your app, you can create a filter to Android Studio Logcat for that log tag: ^(?!(FirebaseRemoteConfig))

Comment: It would be very helpful if you can link your bug report here @hrk

Comment: @Sp4Rx Reference on their side is [3-1516000026221] but I only get the answer via mail on May 9th. that's why I couldn't link it.

Comment: If you are using pidcat, you can filter this out this way: $ ~/.pidcat.py com.example.your_app -i FirebaseRemoteConfig

Comment: Am I reading this correctly? "We don't care much about the developer experience"

Comment: Is there someone working this issue, like a Github issue or so? I'm developing a Flutter app and the following logs have filled the whole console.

`W/FirebaseRemoteConfig(27778): No value of type 'String' exists for parameter key 'sessions_max_length_minutes'.`

Comment: Logcat spam rookie fail. Firebase Perf team get to keep the Raggedy Andy on their desk for the next 6 months.

Comment: Issue still persist in firebase-perf:19.0.5

Comment: If anybody reads this because they have the same issue, upvote this on Github: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/2005

Note: just upvote with , no need to comment.

Comment: Stackoverflow should add a smily below vote-up and vote-down button...

Comment: Still persists on :19.0.7.

Answer (score 13):

It comes from last versions of `firebase-perf` (for example, 16.2.5), because it has internal `firebase-remote-config` dependency.
I have the same issue, but I don't know how to properly fix this log spam (except "Fold lines like this" option in logcat).
I hope Firebase team will fix it soon.

Comment: Also happening on version 16.2.4. Waiting for a fix.

Comment: Thanks for the "Fold lines like this" suggestion. Did not know it existed.

Answer (score 4):

### Solution

Firebase Performance released version `19.0.8` last week to address log spam issue. (see Release Note https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#2020-07-17) You can update your dependency `com.google.firebase:firebase-perf` to be the same or higher version to validate the fix.

---

### Explaination

To explain more about the reason of this issue: **Firebase Performance** utilizes **Firebase Remote Config** to sample down number of events being sent to Firebase, so it will call Firebase Remote Config API [getValue(String key)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/remoteconfig/FirebaseRemoteConfig#getValue(java.lang.String)) every time it needs the sampling configuration value.

However, Firebase Remote Config fetch happens every 12 hours. It is possible that **configuration value doesn't exist** by the time of development. In this case, Firebase Performance SDK will use **default value**.

When the configuration value doesn't exist, **Firebase Remote Config** will generate this log for warning, which is the source of log spam for Firebase Performance users. (See [Source Code](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/blob/5301121df4727b357293b3b7de00555362f90170/firebase-config/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/remoteconfig/internal/ConfigGetParameterHandler.java#L412))

We have reduced **Firebase Performance**'s call frequency to **Firebase Remote Config** to avoid triggering this log.

Answer (score 3):

If you use Firebase Console, setting both values in the Remote Config tab stops the warnings.

I've used: (as string values)

- Parameter key: sessions_max_length_minutes | Value: "15"
- Parameter key: sessions_feature_enabled | Value: "true"

Not sure if there are any side effects, but (hopefully) it's an internal testing thing and doesn't change anything.

Comment: I don't confirm this to work. We added these keys and it didn't help.

Comment: I believed that Firebase Performance uses Remote Config _itself_, as an implementation detail (having its own Firebase project owned by Google).

Answer (score 2):

Firebase Performance Monitoring uses Firebase Remote Config internally.  You can't change the output, but you can [send feedback to the team](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/) using the link that I gave in the comment above.

Answer (score 1):

> The Firebase Android library firebase-core is no longer needed. This
>   SDK included the Firebase SDK for Google Analytics.

Remove firebase-core in your build.gradle

Comment: This is the best answer for anyone looking at this question in 2020 - see https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android

Answer (score 0):

This might be related to, or a result of:

```
W/zzd: Application name is not set. Call Builder#setApplicationName
```

disabling `perf-plugin` & `firebase-perf` removes the annoying log entries:

```
// classpath "com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.2.1"
// apply plugin: "com.google.firebase.firebase-perf"
// implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:17.0.0"
```

`firebase-config` works fine on it's own.

Answer (score 0):

This was my observation:

If you have a specific `key` set up on RemoteConfig **console** & have not added a `default` key in the default xml (passed in `setDefaultsAsync()`).

And if, for some rare case,
either the there was No Connectivity or Firebase RemoteConfig failed to fetch the values & if that specific `key` was used to get a default value,
you might get that message in the Logcat.