# Unknown Firebase Service Crash in Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, google-cloud-firestore

I had made little to no changes in my code but today, as soon as I ran my app on my device, it gave an exception, and did not fetch my data from my Firebase database. I looked up the error on StackOverflow and Github, these are the links I have visited

https://github.com/libgdx/gdx-pay/issues/114

[FirebaseRemoteConfig Error "No value of type 'String' exists for parameter key"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55510223/firebaseremoteconfig-error-no-value-of-type-string-exists-for-parameter-key)

[Firebase Remote Config Fetch failed with user not authorized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54603283/firebase-remote-config-fetch-failed-with-user-not-authorized)

**Log**

```
W/ConnectionTracker: Exception thrown while unbinding
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: tin@934894f
```

```
W/FirebaseRemoteConfig: No value of type 'String' exists for parameter key 'sessions_max_length_minutes'.
W/FirebaseRemoteConfig: No value of type 'String' exists for parameter key 'sessions_feature_enabled'.
W/FirebaseRemoteConfig: No value of type 'String' exists for parameter key 'sessions_feature_enabled'.
W/FirebaseRemoteConfig: No value of type 'String' exists for parameter key 'sessions_max_length_minutes'.
W/FirebaseRemoteConfig: No value of type 'String' exists for parameter key 'sessions_feature_enabled'.
W/FirebaseRemoteConfig: No value of type 'String' exists for parameter key 'sessions_max_length_minutes'.
W/FirebaseRemoteConfig: No value of type 'String' exists for parameter key 'sessions_feature_enabled'.
W/FirebaseRemoteConfig: No value of type 'String' exists for parameter key 'sessions_max_length_minutes'.
```

```
E/FirebaseInstanceId: binding to the service failed
```

**Dependencies**

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.4.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.1'
```

Comment if you want more data from the Logcat or if you want to see any of my code.
Thank you!

Comment: For firebase related issue you can report to the free Firebase Support for further assistance:

https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact?authuser=0

Comment: can I see all Logcat  you got