# Error FirebaseRemoteConfig: No value of type exists for parameter key including firebase-remote-config

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

I added Remote Config of Firebase to my project which this description:

- compileSdkVersion 30
- multiDexEnabled true
- minSdkVersion 16
- targetSdkVersion 30
- Gradle Versioon 6.1.1
- Android gradle plugin version 4.0.2

Depedencies:

- implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:21.1.0'
- implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.4.1'
- implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:18.0.3'

And into a fragment class I call to fetch variables from remote config with this code template:

```
final Context mContext = this.getActivity().getBaseContext().getApplicationContext();
mFirebaseRemoteConfig = FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance();
mFirebaseRemoteConfig.fetch(0).addOnCompleteListener(this.getActivity(), new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            mFirebaseRemoteConfig.fetchAndActivate();
        }

        String myVariable = mFirebaseRemoteConfig.getString("myVariable");        
    }
});
```

When I run the project and is moment to fetch variables, "myVariable" doesn't have any value assigned, and I reviewing in Logcat and the error says:

> W/FirebaseRemoteConfig: No value of type 'String' exists for parameter
> key 'myVariable'.

I have researched and I found the same error, reasons and possible solutions like this post:

[FirebaseRemoteConfig Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55510223/firebaseremoteconfig-error-no-value-of-type-string-exists-for-parameter-key)

I implemented the solution adding *firebase-remote-config* in dependencies section into build.gradle:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:19.0.8'
```

And I have the same result, that variables don't fetch getting empty value and the same error.

I have already checked the applicationId in Firebase and my Config file and it is correct, both of them have the same ID. The only difference that I can have is that I have two Firebase Android apps (one for PROD and another for QA) and I made Build Variants for PROD and QA but I have Analytics and Crashlytics and they are saving records.

Anyone have some solution for this or help me to discover my mistake, please?